# How to load an image file into a Django File object, then save into a FileField of my model

Tags: python, django, image, django-staticfiles

So I've spent more than 24 hours trying to figure out how to store an image into my model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    avatar = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='www-avatar/')
```

My `Profile Model` has an attribute `avatar` which stands for the profile picture.

What I want to do is after the `User` has finished the sign-up process, the `Profile` Model would then be assigned a default image from my static folder.

Here is my Settings.py for static

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/foo/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "bar/resource/"), )
```

And the image that I want to load and store into the model is in `bar/resource/profile_light.png`

So far, the solution I've come up is with this

```
file = File()
url = static("bar/resource/profile_light.png")
file = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
r = File(file)
authbox.profile.avatar = File(file)
authbox.profile.save()
```

To no avail. I am new to Django and I would very much appreciate any form of help.

EDIT: I may have worded my question poorly, but I need to add a default image on the profiles that are created. The snippet i gave above of the saving of the avatar is located after the sign up process. So basically I want to access the image every time someone signs up, and the image gets stored as their default avatar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly change the field type in your `models.py` as:

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='www-avatar/', null=True)
```

secondly, in your settings file you should define a media directory

```
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "www-avatar")
```

then, you should modify your `urls.py` file as

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
.......

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

last but not least do not forget to install pillow library `pip install Pillow` (https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.1/)

Comment: Pardon me for a probably stupid question but, do I necessarily have to define a media_directory for this? Since the image is within the project and It is only one, would a relative url work as well? I'm really not knowledgeable in the topic and would just like to clarify.

Comment: Due to policies, I do not have the luxury to tweak the `Models`, but if I get a sufficient reason to do so, which I believe is beyond my knowledge as of now, I might be able to convince the higher people to allow me to refactor.

Comment: If there are only static files that you defined from backend like styles and javascript you don't need, but if you expect files that will be uploaded by users get a url and then served you must use it. Read : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: understood, I am currently testing it now and I'll get back to you as soon as I can. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer helped me understand the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='www-avatar', default='path/to/my/default/image.jpg')
```

Comment: I may have worded my question poorly, but I need to add a `default image` on the profiles that are created. The Initial snippet i gave of the saving of the avatar is located `after` the `sign up` process. So basically I want to access the image everytime someone signs up, and the image gets stored as their default avatar.

Comment: Concerning the path, is it supposedly relative or absolute?

Comment: Absolute using your `static` variables.